# How is the ledger actually stored at a node?

Tags: node, storage

How are the information about the transactions actually stored in a Tangle? I mean to say, how is the transaction data or simply some data(stored as a zero-valued transaction) actually stored in some database, so that it can be easily accessed, queried and traced.